# Python data structures and class

Tags: python, class, data-structures

If we have :

```
K = [3,4,5]
T = (3,4,5)
```

and we call these commands :

```
print(type(K))
print(type(T))
```

we have these prints :

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'tuple'>
```

I know that K is a list and T is a tuple, but I'm not sure whether K or T are also classes or not ?
We have commands like K.append() and similar commands, this makes me unsure about the concept.

Comment: Try typing: `K.__class__`

Comment: Everything in Python is an object, and everything has a type (their class).

Comment: @brianpck: `type(K)` returns `K.__class__`.

Comment: `K` and `T` are not themselves classes. They are *instances*; one is an instance of the `list` class, the other of `tuple`.

Comment: Just because something has an _attribute_ (i.e. `foo.bar`) doesn't mean it is an instance of a class.  Non-class objects can have attributes too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh I think I got it. list and tuples are classes in python, but here K and T are instances of those classes. right?

Comment: @JohnGordon Everything is an instance of some class.

Answer (score 0):

K and T are instances of python's List and Tuple data types. Types generally have some associated attributes, just like classes. See more about data structures and implementation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

These are not necessarily class objects, however. This SO post should clarify [the difference between a data type and a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780435/what-is-the-differences-between-class-and-datatype).

Answer (score 0):

List and tuple are build-in classes in Python, that's why you can write list() to create a list and tuple() to create a tuple. You just creating an instance of the class list/tuple. You can also deckare a list by using "[" and "]" and a tuple by using "(" and ")", because these so called "operators" are standard syntax of Python.